# jmeter webdriver not able to click login popup

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium, jmeter

**This the header script**

```
<header>
        <div class="meta" role="banner">
            <a class="logo" href="//www.test.com"></a>
            <ul class="navigation-meta"></ul>
        </div>
        <nav class="navigation-main" role="navigation">
            <ul class="navigation">
                ::before
                <div></div>
                <li class="toggle-mobile-menu"></li>
                <li class="cscs">
                    **<a class="" href="#">**

                                ::before

                                My Login

                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="search"></li>
                        ::after
                    </ul>
                    <div class="login-position-wrap open"></div>
                    <!--

                     Logout Popup 

                    -->
                    <div data-app-type="LogoutOverlay" data-app-launched="LogoutOverlay"></div>
                </nav>
                <script></script>
            </header>
```

**After i Click Mauel on MyLogin **

```
<header>
        <div class="meta" role="banner">
            <a class="logo" href="//www.test.com"></a>
            <ul class="navigation-meta"></ul>
        </div>
        <nav class="navigation-main" role="navigation">
            <ul class="navigation">
                ::before
                <div></div>
                <li class="toggle-mobile-menu"></li>
                <li class="cscs">
                    <a class="active" href="#">

                                ::before

                                My Login

                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="search"></li>
                        ::after
                    </ul>
                    <div class="login-position-wrap open"></div>
                    <!--

                     Logout Popup 

                    -->
                    <div data-app-type="LogoutOverlay" data-app-launched="LogoutOverlay"></div>
                </nav>
                <script></script>
            </header>
```

**this my Jmeter script**

1. var pkg=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium) //import java selenium package
2. var support_ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait) //import WebDriverWait Package
3. WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() //sample starting point
   WDS.browser.get('http://www.test.com')
4. var openField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.className("cscs"))
   openField.click()
5. var usernameField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('email'))
6. usernameField.click()
7. usernameField.sendKeys(['Test@gmail.com'])
8. var passwordField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('password'))

In step 4 is faild

Answer (score 1):

Try switch to popup

```
    WDS.browser.switchTo.alert()
```